# Visual Studio Team Services and Appharbor

Tags: tfs, appharbor, azure-devops

I know you can configure [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) to run with Team Foundation Server but is it possible to do the same with Visual Studio Team Services (http://visualstudio.com). I have checked AppHarbor's website and also searched but can't find any relevant information on this.

Comment: Thanks friism for correcting my post and not answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking into this myself...looks like you can only do this via Codeplex

i.e.

- Create a Codeplex project and configure it
- Check-in your code to Codeplex using TFS
- Codeplex notifies Appharbor
- Appharbor pulls the code and builds/deploys it to your app.

Instructions for Codeplex integration can be found here:

http://support.appharbor.com/kb/3rd-party-integrations/integrating-with-codeplex